# Dplyr selecting multpiple rows fails

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm learning dplyr to integrate it in my workflow and I am trying to select cases from a large dataset. I am using what I believe is simple and straight forward code for simple manipulations such as this but it fails. Why, escapes me.

Any insights into what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Here is an example from which I get the same error message:

```
City <- c("city1", "city2", "city3", "city4")
var1 <- c(7.5, 9.4, 8.6, 24)
var2 <- c(8, 10, 16, 18)
var3 <- c(1400, 1700, 1800, 3500)
LFA <- data.frame(City, var1, var2, var3)
LFA
```

Data frame:

```
City var1 var2 var3
1 city1  7.5    8 1400
2 city2  9.4   10 1700
3 city3  8.6   16 1800
4 city4 24.0   18 3500
```

I am trying to subset for smaller areas by doing this:

```
StateLFA <- LFA %>%
    filter(City=="city1" & City=="city3") %>%
    select(City, var1, var2)
```

I get this:

```
[1] City var1 var2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: May be you need `LFA %>% filter(City %in% c('city1', 'city3')) %>% select(-var3)` or use `filter(City=='city1' |City =='city3')` as an element can't be both `city1` and `city3`

Comment: Thank you akrun, I was confused with the operators. The "|" worked. I'm grateful for the help and I am learning fast because of this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as akrun wrote, just replace the & with a |

```
> StateLFA <- LFA %>%
> filter(City=="city1" | City=="city3") %>%
> select(City, var1, var2)
```

for more information on operators, look at http://www.statmethods.net/management/operators.html

There is a nice introduction to operators at
http://www.lib.berkeley.edu/TeachingLib/Guides/Internet/Boolean.pdf

Comment: Wow, I am ashamed that I didn't figure that one out. I am familiar with boolean operators but for some reason, I thought the OR meant one or the other and needed an additional condition. I really thought the & was the right one and I didn't even try another operator. Such an amateur mistake. Thank you kindly for the answer, I will read the linked sources as well.